# Is it possible to restore a Windows system disk encrypted with BitLocker after format?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, restore, format, bitlocker

I accidentally formatted my Windows 7 OS disk from my secondary OS in a moment of carelessness.

It was an encrypted drive with BitLocker. I have not touched it since the formatting took place. Is it at all possible to somehow undo the format?

More specifically, I am asking about any method which may undo the flags or similar set by the formatting process. As it was a "quick format" and did not actually delete anything, it just marked the whole drive as free.

Answer (score 2):

When a drive is formatted (taking NTFS as an example), a new MFT and mirror MFT are written to the disk.  This at least partially overwrites the existing MFTs.  Unformatting is not as simple as resetting a couple flags.

Windows writes and reads back each sector on a volume on a standard format to test for bad blocks ([reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686), [reference](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/difference-windows-full-format-quick-format-technology-explained/)).  This obliterates any data on the drive.  Windows skips this step for a quick format.

What needs to be done is to scan the entire volume for things that look like files and rebuild the MFT manually.  I don't know of a tool that specifically does this, tools I've used like [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) will help you copy the files off but not restore it to bootable status (except if it's just a simple partition/MBR overwrite or error, which is easier to restore from).

Comment: KB302686 has vanished sadly.. archive.org link: http://web.archive.org/web/20130926142721/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686